# Locked post's error message for comment is not correct

Tags: bug, comments, error-message, locked-questions

In the list of [locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=locked%3A1), when I'm trying to upvote a comment, receiving the following error message as a popup.

> This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging

But I am able to flag the comment. That is not matched with the error message. Can the error message be corrected?

> [image: unable to comment upvote]